# insert / prepend new div with contents to populate before specific div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a large scale website where each page contains a google map with the id `#google_map_vc_box` **I am wondering if I could use JS or jQuery to insert new a div with it's contains before specific div** of `#google_map_vc_box` across the entire website.

Recent attempt, but no cigar *(also seems like a pretty ugly / clunky solution)*

```
var $container = $('#google_map_vc_box'),
    $d = $container.find('div');

var $n = $('<div>', {
    data: {
        id: new
    },
    text: sup
});

var $a = $d.filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('id') < new;
}).first();

if ($a.length) $a.after($n)
else $container.prepend($n);
```

Comment: You want to insert the new `<div>` (that you created) *before* the `$('#google_map_vc_box')` element? Please, for the sake of the sanity of those that want to help you, *show* us HTML, don't describe it at us...

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes I do! Just tried this, but didn't work as well!     $( "#google_map_vc_box" ).prepend( $( "#banners" ) );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `$n`, newly-created `<div>`, given the clarifications in the comments to your question, and insert that element before the `#google_map_vc_box` element:

```
$n.insertBefore('#google_map_vc_box');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8L085cz9/3/).

Or:

```
$('#google_map_vc_box').before($n);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8L085cz9/3/).

And, with plain JavaScript, it's not hard:

```
var $n = document.createElement('div');
$n.id = 'new'; // remember to quote this value, unless it's a variable
var googleBox = document.getElementById('google_map_vc_box');

googleBox.parentNode.insertBefore($n, googleBox);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8L085cz9/).

Or even:

```
var googleBox = document.getElementById('google_map_vc_box');

googleBox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div id="new"></div>');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8L085cz9/1/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Node.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML).
  - [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- jQuery:

  - [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).
  - [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

Comment: Now the problem is; when google_map_vc_box is not present on the page the banners just populate at the top of the page

Comment: That shouldn't happen at all. In both situations the selector is based on the existence of the `#google_maps_vc_box` element; if it doesn't exist jQuery doesn't even attempt to insert the `$n` element; and plain JavaScript will error out, given that there's a `null` reference. So: for that assertion to stand you *really* need to provide relevant evidence to prove the claim. (I accept that *something* may be happening, but the way *I* wrote the code that *cannot* happen; your implementation, however, may allow that.)

Comment: I've called it like this with jQuery     $( "#google_map_vc_box" ).before( $( "#banners" ) );

Comment: That's weird, then; can you reproduce that behaviour with a JS Fiddle, by any chance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62363/discussion-between-captain-ron-and-david-thomas).

Comment: I PM'd you URL in chat, if you wanted too look -- where should I have inline mark-up?